# How to run program/application in full screen mode

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scripts, fullscreen

I am running my program/application from command line like sudo ./MyApp and some of programs I run like sudo ./MyShFile.sh ( in .sh file I just call/run my programs).

But I want that my program should be run in full screen mode in Ubuntu 14.04.

If anybody has any idea about the same then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `wmctrl -r nameofwindow -b add,fullscreen`

Comment: @VRR How do I find the name of the window? is that what's shown on the title bar?